# Find exercises infinite sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-theory

Where can I find exercises with infinite sets (to check if they are countable or not)?

I have searched the web and didn't find anything if you have a link i would appreciate it if you post it.

Comment: Why don't you try to search for Wikipedia topics on "countable and uncountable sets"?

Comment: @Subhajit Wikipedia is not a textbook -- https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:NOTTEXTBOOK -- and so it doesn't include exercises.

Comment: These kinds of exercises would probably be most readily found in books titled something like: 'Foundations in Mathematics'.

Comment: Can read Russian?

Comment: Nope I am from UK.

Comment: Try search on this site "is countable" perhaps.